# How to extract relevant information from article using Python? NLP+RegEX?

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp

I am writing a program in Python to scan articles for topics that I am interested in. I want to filter out sentences related to the topic from many articles, then create a summary.

I have been using regex but often missing the sentence if it is not using the keywords. Worse than that, I often only get the questions regarding my keywords, leaving out the answers that matter the most.

For example, if I am interested in "Trump" in the article below:

"..... What's your view on Trump's foreign policy? I don't think anyone can give a clear answer but I think he is likely to do whatever it takes to contain the public health issue first.
....."

By using "Trump" as the keywords via Regex, I only get the question highlighted, not the answer in the following sentence.

What techniques that I can use to select all relevant info? Open for natural language processing techniques, ideally available from open source packages can help me to do this?

Need not to be a perfect solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the selenium package or requests/urllib + beautifulsoup4.

If you're trying to compare multiple sites, you'll have to have a tailored parser for each site.

If you need help with a specific site, let me know.

Comment: hey thanks! the question is more about how to get all relevant info instead of just the sentences with keywords.